# Finding issues in a code snippet

Tags: c

I need help with a screening question (in C) asked by a company.

The question is to find out issues with the below code.

```
short test() {
   short a,b,c;
   b=10;
   c = a + b;
   return c; 
}
```

Also, what if the signature is changed to short test(short a) and a is removed from the stack?

I cannot seem to find any issues with this code except that junk values could get stored in 'a' as it is not initialized. And for the second question, what difference does it really make if 'a' is passed as argument to the function? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Well, don't you think that "junk values stored in a' is an issue?

Comment: Yes I do, but I thought I am missing something else as the same question is asked with the function having 'a' as an argument.

Comment: Note: Any parameters passed to the `test()` are not used as it has no arguments specified. (or visa-versa)

Comment: Also a problem of overflow?

Comment: I tried running the above code in Ubuntu and Windows(Dev C++), both are behaving differently. So I think the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `a` is indeterminate because it is uninitialized.  Reading `a` results in undefined behavior.  If `a` were passed into the function and it was also uninitialized the same problem would occur, only sooner.